# How to use python to add a processing instruction node?

Tags: python, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add an xml-stylesheet processing instruction node with Python 2.6 and minidom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648343/python-2-6-minidom-toprettyxml-how-to-output-xml-meta-data-with-document-xsl)

I meet a issue about using the minidom by python. I need add a line like

```
<?tag XXXXX?>
```

However, I find this is not a DOM, it seems that I can't use the DOM to manipulate. Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an XML processing instruction.

You want the createProcessingInstruction() API method. See

[How to add an xml-stylesheet processing instruction node with Python 2.6 and minidom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648343/python-2-6-minidom-toprettyxml-how-to-output-xml-meta-data-with-document-xsl/5651055#5651055)

for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You're issue is that it is the header.  The answer then could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982887/how-to-add-xml-header-to-dom-object) or just add the header and footer around the code like so:

```
return header + 'xmlstring' + footer
```